# I have some issue with Visibility of YouTubePlayer in android?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have issue with youtube player view in android.

its show bellow error when its play some time it's play then suddenly its stop.
And show bellow error.

```
YouTube video playback stopped because the player's view is not visible.
The view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
{36d050c2 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-540,960} has visibility "INVISIBLE".
```

Tell me what can i do for this error.??

My Activity code is here.

```
youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
youTubePlayerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, this);


@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    myYouTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    // Change play style
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
    youTubePlayer
            .addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this);
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(this);
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
                errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My XML file code is here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_FullScreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000" >

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rl_CurrentVideoDetails"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_Heading"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rl_ChannelChange"
    android:background="#000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_ChannelChange"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background_black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_ChNo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Ch."
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_ChNo"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_CurrentVideoDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background_black"
    android:paddingStart="12dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_CurrentVideoName"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="| Ch. "
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_NormalScreen"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try giving some fixed specific values to youtube player's height and width,see if it works.

Comment: No its not work still have issue.

Comment: use the latest youtube api which can be found at their offical site and also run your app on updated Youtube app.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @GyanendraMani... i do that but still its not working bro

Comment: @GyanendraMani... Is there any other solution? tell me as soon as possible...

Comment: I have had the same issue just now - I am not sure of a solution, but I know it was working a few days ago. Perhaps a change Google have made?

Please give an update if you get anywhere with this!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue on my app last night and eventually found a solution (for me at least). It appears there was always an issue in my app, I was accidentally launching the same intent to my YoutubePlayerActivity multiple times.

Previously, this went un-noticed by myself - however the recent Youtube update must have increased the restriction or changed the way it works as I then got this error.

I went through my code and found that when I add fragments, it was re-calling onCreateView of every fragment. Meaning for all three fragments added, I eventually called the intent three times.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: so u mean u have to check that i m recallning that frgment in activity?

Comment: nice observation. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if your Youtube App has been update last September or later?
It seems there is a bug in Youtube App, that causes this estrange error when using Youtube API:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7586

You can check if this error is caused by Youtube App easily, removing Youtube App updates and testing your app. You can remove an this app updates going to Settings > General > Apps > Youtube and click in Uninstall Updates button.

For me, this was the reason my app youtube videos not working well. When I uninstall updates my app works, when I reinstall updates my app crash again. So, I think the only solution is wait for new update :(

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> YouTube video playback stopped because the player's view is not
>   visible.

**Nothing should overlap the `YouTubePlayerView`** (as required by Google's policy). This means that you need to consider the z-index and/or overlapping of all the views in your hierarchy.

In your case, **the order of the elements in the XML files determines the z-index** and there's a *match_parent* layout which overlaps the `YouTubePlayerView`: you need to bring the `YouTubePlayerView` to front, just move it as last item in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_ChannelChange"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background_black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_ChNo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Ch."
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_ChNo"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_CurrentVideoDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent_background_black"
    android:paddingStart="12dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_CurrentVideoName"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="| Ch. "
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_NormalScreen"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rl_CurrentVideoDetails"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_Heading"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rl_ChannelChange"
    android:background="#000" />
```